# How to export X Display with Audio?

Tags: sound, xorg, tty

How can I export my X Display with audio.

For example,
in tty1 if I put, "startx xmoto -- :1 &", I can play xmoto ok, but have no sound.
If I put "xinit -- :1 &"and then put "xmoto &", again I can play xmoto ok, but have no sound.

The strange thing is the sound continues in tty1...if I go back to tty1 (ctrl+alt+f1) I can hear the game, but in tty8 (ctrl+alt+f8) didnt have sound.

So, probably I need to know how to export the X Display and the sound to tty8, for example.

Comment: I can't completely anwser your question, but I can start you on your way. X doesn't handle the sound, if you're using Natty its pulseaudio.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

///OLD: Left just in case!
This worked for me

edit /etc/group

```
sudo nano /etc/group
```

Next, search for audio, you shoud find somethink like this:

```
audio:x:29:pulse
```

Add a coma and your username afther pulse

```
audio:x:29:pulse,username //whatever your username actually is
```

**change username with the one you wish to log in!!!**

Save and restart ubuntu, it should work. 
If I switch between sessions(Cn+Alt+F7), I loose sound in the one I started, just to let you all know. I suppose it is a bug.

///OLD

EDIT: According to Reinis(see comment below) it is not recommended to edit the file manually. It's better to :

```
sudo adduser _username_ audio
```

Change *username* with your actual username. Restart :)

Comment: Really thanks, worked to me too. Interesting, similar problems can solved by this.

Comment: You shouldn't edit that file manually. The better way would be to use command:
"sudo adduser username audio"
I can't say the reason for this but I guess security and/or data consistency.
I would upvote You would kindly fix the solution :)

Comment: No need to reboot, just log out, and log in again.