# startx, gui on tty7 and sound on tty 1

Tags: sound, xorg, pulseaudio, alsa, tty

I just installed ubuntu minimal and fluxbox. I have installed no login manager, so after the system boots, I login in the tty1 and use the `startx` command to run.

After that, if I open Firefox and go to a youtube video (or use `aplay` to play a wav file) I have no sound. alsamixer is unmutted and all. However, if I switch back to tty1, I can hear the sound playing!

Why this is happening, and how to tell to startx that I want the sound on the TTY which the gui is presented?

Comment: take a look at: http://askubuntu.com/questions/45604/how-to-export-x-display-with-audio

Comment: @Seth Thanks, but according to [ubuntu docs](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Audio/TheAudioGroup) it is not a good idea adding the user to the audio group. And it didn't worked for me. He also states: `If I switch between sessions(Cn+Alt+F7), I loose sound in the one I started, just to let you all know. I suppose it is a bug.` which don't looks nice

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A way to solve this problem is to disable pulseaudio   .

*(note that pulseaudio is usually not  needed to get sound, as almost all Linux software can use alsa if pulseaudio is not active. Exception is Skype which needs pulseaudio  .

The main problem is that you must install and use **gnome-alsamixer** to set volume instead standard volume applet.

Another problem is that you will lose auto-switching between usb device and internal soundcard that pulseaudio permits )*

So, to disable pulseaudio in a easily reversible way, run successively this 3 commands in a terminal:

```
mkdir ~/.pulse
echo autospawn=no > ~/.pulse/client.conf
pulseaudio -k
```

then reboot (logout could be ok ), and test .

If you want pulseaudio again, just run   in a terminal :
`pulseaudio -D`
Run also
`echo autospawn=yes > ~/.pulse/client.conf`
if you want  pulseaudio to be auto-launched at next reboot or logon.

EDIT: Running pulseaudio in **daemon mode** is also ok , see [this](https://askubuntu.com/questions/544925/failed-to-open-audio-output-error-when-trying-to-send-audio-from-mpd-to-pulsea/549128#549128)

Comment: Cool, thanks. Can you explain how pulseaudio works with different ttys? I believe that it should have a way to instead of disabling it, redirect the sound to other tty, right?

Comment: daemon mode for pulseaudio is a workaround, (edited the answer).